# Installing Flash Media Server on a live Linux host

Tags: flash-media-server

I'm playing around with Flash Media Server, and got it streaming my webcam live through the browser. 
I will like to be able to stream live on the web. However, I'm confused as to how the process works on the web. On my localhost, all I had to do was install the executable file, use rtmp://localhost/live as the source, then create the swf file and HTML to broadcast it. 
 My questions are these: 
    I already have a Virtual Dedicated Server, and unless it can't be done, I don't want to purchase a Flash Media Server account with another FMS host. Do I have to install FMS on my server? 
    If yes, how do I install it on a Linux host? 
    Are there extra steps that I need to take, in order to make it work just on my localhost? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved; I simply purchased an account on a site offering a Flash Media Server services, uploaded the files, created the logic using ActionScript3.0; everything's fine at that point.